# image title tag missing in PIL and pyexiv2 after Lightroom export

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, lightroom, pyexiv2

Lightroom allows to modify photo's Title and ImageDescription tags. Title is a non-conform EXIF tag, so it is saved it somewhere else, but not in the EXIF tags directly.

I want to parse image tags using Python. I tried using PIL and pyexiv2. Neither can retrieve image title from the EXIF tags, though it can be seen in Windows' File properties/details window.

I use Python 2.7.2 32bit on Windows 7 home.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange that no-one could help, but I have figured it out by now.

JPG image information is stored in `EXIF` and `IPTC` tags. Adobe Lightroom stores title and image description in `IPTC.Application.Caption` & `IPTC.Application.ImageDescription` tags. Adobe Photoshop stores headline and image description in `IPTC.Application.Headline` & `IPTC.Application.ImageDescription` respectively. These tags can be easily extracted using [`pyexiv2`](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/):

```
import pyexiv2

# read image
metadata = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(path_to_image)
metadata.read()

# now the metadata has been parsed and is ready to be extracted
title = metadata[Iptc.Application2.Caption][0]
imageDescription = metadata[Iptc.Application2.ImageDescription][0]
```

See [here](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/tutorial.html#reading-and-writing-iptc-tags) for more info to `IPTC` tags in `pyexiv2`.

Comment: I came across this issue myself ..  found that the LR Title was stored in the ObjectName property, instead of Caption  Thanks for figuring it out!